# Is there a way to pass default case value as an argument

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to see if there is a way that I can incorporate the default case's value in a match expression

```
item match {
case null => false
case _:String => _.matches(params)
}
```

I've tried looking at different options, but I couldn't really find a solution.

For context this is part of this snippet of code, performing it on a `spark dataframe`

```
x.filter(row => row.getAs[String]("colname").matches("""/regex/""")).count()
```

but there are ocassional `null` values that make everything break.

I know I can do this to get the desired result, but doesn't make sense to calculate it again

```
x.filter(row => row.getAs[String]("colname") match{
         case null => false
         case _ => row.getAs[String]("colname").matches("""\d""")
         }).count()
```

Any suggestions or pointers would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: dont use an underscore , use a lowercase variable identifier to be able to reference the value

Comment: I don't understand your statement ` but doesn't make sense to calculate it again`, what do you mean with this?

Comment: I'm calling this twice `row => row.getAs[String]("colname")`

Answer (score 3):

To match everything you just need to use variable name without type ascription:

```
item match {
   case null => false
   case i => i.matches(params)
}
```

So in your case:

```
x.filter(row => 
   row.getAs[String]("colname") match {
         case null => false
         case r => r.matches("""\d""")
   }
).count()
```

If you want to check if the item is null, you could also use `Option.apply` which returns `None` if the value is `null` and `Some` otherwise, for example:

```
Option(item).fold(false)(_.matches(params))
```

Comment: the variable name method wouldn't really work for me here because I'm creating the value before the match `row => row.getAs[String]("colname") `

Comment: I doesn't make diference where are you creating value, please check my example.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Krzysztof Atłasik answer, you can add the check for null before the match-statament, you could  do:

```
x
.where($"colname".isNotNull)
.filter(row => row.getAs[String]("colname").matches("""/regex/""")).count()
```

or something like

```
x.where($"colname" rlike """\d""").count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use rlike. For example:

```
x.filter(x("colName").rlike("cat|dog")).count
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you are looking to filter and aggregate in a single iteration and I think UDAF is something you will have to go for. Essentially, I don't see any performance benefits of doing this over the option mentioned at the end of your original post i.e. udf to filter out and then a count. However, I have demonstrated how the UDAF can be used here.

For Spark<3.0, you will have to extend the UserDefinedAggregateFunction class to look somewhat like this -

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{MutableAggregationBuffer, UserDefinedAggregateFunction}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

    class ConditionalCount(val pattern: String, colName: String) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction{
      override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Seq(StructField(colName, StringType)))

      override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(Seq(StructField("count", LongType)))

      override def dataType: DataType = LongType

      override def deterministic: Boolean = true

      override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = buffer(0) = 0L

      override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
        buffer(0) = buffer.getAs[Long](0) + input.getAs[String](0) match {
          case null => 0
          case x if x.matches(pattern) => 1L
          case _ => 0L
        }
      }

      override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit =
        buffer1(0) = buffer1.getAs[Long](0) + buffer2.getAs[Long](0)

      override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = buffer.getAs[Long](0)
    }
```

Then use this initialize and use this UDAF to look like something like this -

```
    val conditionalCount = new ConditionalCount("my pattern", "colName")

    df.withColumn("count", conditionalCount(col("colName")))
```

P.S.: I have not run this and verified, pardon me if there are minute errors

Comment: this is a huge overkill, see other SQL-based solutions posted here

Comment: I have mentioned the same if you have read my answer, but it was just to highlight what does it look like to the user is trying to achieve!!

Comment: you miss the point - not even simple udf is required here